# object oriented programming, constructor with parameters

Tags: java, oop, constructor

So here is the code, and there are few lines I don't understand.

```
account acct = new account(); // making a new object named acct, type:account

ConsoleAccountEvents c1 = new ConsoleAccountEvents(acct); // new object created with parameters.

acct.addObserver(c1); // also not sure. 

acct.addTransaction(100.00); // not sure....
```

This is Java. I'm not sure how parameters are passed to the constructor.

Comment: A constructor with parameters is generally called an 'Overloaded constructor' in most Object Oriented Programming languages. A constructor is called when you create an object. By passing data to a constructor, you are passing data to the object that is being created.

Comment: so what is acct here? just parameter? so we are declaring another variable here?

Comment: `acct` is an `Object`. Just so you know, each language has naming conventions; Classes start with an upper case letter. Once you make the Account Object named acct; you pass it to the `ConsoleAccountEvents(Account a)` constructor.

Comment: oh yes I see that, so we are putting object as a parameter?

Comment: and I don't understand acct.addObserver(c1)

Comment: Yes. `ConsoleAccountEvents` constructor is defined along the lines of `ConsoleAccountEvents(Account account){...}`. acct.addObserver(c1) is the same thing; passing an Object to a constructor.

Comment: I'm still not sure so acct is an object and we are passing c1 which is also an object to a method named addObserver then?

Comment: You need to review the [Java Language Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) in its entirety. Asking random questions on the Internet is no way to learn a language. Too broad.

Answer (score 1):

In java, the constructor is invoked when the object of the class is created using the `new` keyword. So to call the constructor with a certain parameter you just have to create an object with parameter as per your requirement example in your case.

```
class ConsoleAccountEvents {

    Account account;

    public ConsoleAccountEvents(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
}

class Account {

}
```

So when you create object with

```
Account acct = new Account(); 
ConsoleAccountEvents c1 = new ConsoleAccountEvents(acct);
```

So here parameterized constructor will be called and this object will be assigned in instance variable of `ConsoleAccountEvents` class

Answer (score 0):

Your `ConsoleAccountEvents` class must look like something like this-

```
class ConsoleAccountEvents {
    Account accObject; // you have an object of 'Account' class as a member variable in this class
    // other variables
    public ConsoleAccountEvents() {
        // body here
    }
    public ConsoleAccountEvents(Account accObject) {
        this.accObject = accObject; // see below
        // body here
    }
    // others
}
```

Doing this `ConsoleAccountEvents c1 = new ConsoleAccountEvents(acct);`

You are calling the parametrized constructor which takes an `Account` object as parameter and generally initialize the `accObject` (object of `Account` class) in `ConsoleAccountEvents` with it.

Now, For `acct.addObserver(c1);`

In your `Account` class you must have a method `addObserver` that takes a `ConsoleAccountEvents` as parameter. like

```
void addObserver(ConsoleAccountEvents evOb) {
    // body
}
```

***PS:*** Please follow java naming conventions and other conventions, like capitalizing the first letter of name of a class etc.

And stackoverflow is not going to be of much help if you dont go through [Java Language Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). Good luck...!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is how the `new` keyword works, but let me be thorough:

Some things to note about constructing objects in Java:

1. A constructor will be called every time you "request" a `new Account()`.
2. A constructor can be defined to use parameters (and thus require arguments) of any type - both class types and primitive types (int, float, char, etc..)
3. If the constructor is called like `new SomeClass(someObject)`, `someObject` is the argument passed to the constructor of SomeClass.

In the constructor of a class, parameters are defined with a type and a name as such:

```
class ConsoleAccountEvents{
    Account account;

    ConsoleAccountEvents(Account a){
        account = a;
    }
}
```

Here the *parameter* "`a`" is defined to be of the `Account` "type" - the *argument* sent to the constructor must be an instance of the `Account` class, in other words the constructor requires an `Account` object. So in order to construct a `ConsoleAccountEvents` object we must pass it an `Account` object as the *argument* as such:

```
Account acct = new Account();
ConsoleAccountEvents c1 = new ConsoleAccountEvents(acct)
```

Using "new" calls the constructor of the following class. For the Account class, we need no arguments to create an object - it has a *default constructor*, but we need to *use* an Account object - `acct` - as the argument to allow `ConsoleAccountEvents` to be constructed since it's constructor has an Account type parameter in it's definition.

In other languages there are more ways to construct objects. In C++ for example, the programmer can choose which objects should be saved on the "heap" and the "stack" by switching between using the `new` keyword vs calling the constructor directly as if it was any other function. In Java this is not possible. Almost all objects are created using the new keyword or by copying another object in some way. I believe even *serializing* and *deserializing* had to start with `new` at some point to create the first object.